# ext3 linux kernel implementation

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, ext3

I just read http://olstrans.sourceforge.net/release/OLS2000-ext3/OLS2000-ext3.html which is an excellent review of the design issues used when journaling was implemented in ext3. Could someone point me towards the section of the linux kernel code where ext3 journaling is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lxr](http://lxr.linux.no/) to search the linux code.

ext3 and journaling interface code is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37.2/fs/ext3/ext3_jbd.c) and JDB code is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37.2/fs/jbd/transaction.c#L1134)